# Keycloak + postgresql configuration

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

I tried to configure keycloak server with my postgresql db. After many tries with a lot of configs I decided to ask the question.
I have the next configurations:
module.xml which is located in keycloak/modules/org/postgresql/main
Also in that directory I put jdbc-driver with name 'postgresql-42.2.16.jar'

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.16.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

standalone.xml which is located in keycloak/standalone/configuration
In that xml I configured

**drivers:**

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

**datasources:**

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgres://192.168.99.100:5432/keycloak</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
        <pool>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>keycloak</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
         <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
         <driver>h2</driver>
         <security>
             <user-name>sa</user-name>
             <password>sa</password>
         </security>
    </datasource>
 
...
</datasources>
```

**keycloak server config:**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
    <spi name="connectionsJpa">
        <provider name="default" enabled="true">
            <properties>
                <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/>
                <property name="initializeEmpty" value="false"/>
                <property name="migrationStrategy" value="manual"/>
                <property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak-database-update.sql"/>
            </properties>
        </provider>
    </spi>
</subsystem>
```

And when I'm trying to start my keycloak server I got the exception:

```
17:56:19,859 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) 
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS is missing [jboss.jdbc- 
driver.postgresql]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]"
]
}
17:56:19,860 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) 
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
    "jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql",
    "jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql"
],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS is missing [jboss.jdbc- 
driver.postgresql]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]"
]
}
```

It's looks like I configured my datasource in wrong way, but I can't find the error. I checked this [check list](http://1.%20create%20db%20keycloak%20owner%20set%20keycloak%20password%20%27keycloak%27%202.%20download%20jdbc-driver%203.%20create%20foolder:%20../modules/system/layers/keycloak/org/postgresql%204.%20put%20there%20jdbc-driver%205.%20put%20there%20module.xml%206.%20edit%20../standalone/configuration/standalone.xml%20(see%20https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_installation/#_rdbms-setup-checklist)%207.%20edit%20standalone.xml%20change%20ports%20in%20tags:%20%3Csocket-binding%20name=%22http%22%20port=%22$%7Bjboss.http.port:9090%7D%22/%3E%20%3Csocket-binding%20name=%22https%22%20port=%22$%7Bjboss.https.port:9443%7D%22/%3E%208.%20create%20admin:%20./add-user-keycloak.sh%20-r%20master%20-u%20tadm%20-p%20tadm%209.%20open%20admin%20consol:%20http://localhost:9090%2010.%20standalone.conf%20edit%20JAVA_HOME%2011.%20/etc/systemd/system/keycloak.service) and it doesn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please retry with the following connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.99.100:5432/keycloak
```

instead of

```
jdbc:postgres://192.168.99.100:5432/keycloak
```

Also, consider letting the SPI/connectionsJpa block at defaults (I believe in particular that `initializeEmpty` should be true) and I don't remember that I had to add/modify this block, so please double-check.

You may also disable or comment the *ExampleDS* (h2) dataSource.